# why is the NSMutableArray is being destroyed in this loop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

It is the arrayOfPerformances that is getting broken.

here is the .h for the array:

```
    NSMutableArray * arrayOfPerformances;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * arrayOfPerformances;
```

and the .m that has the loop:

```
[dataArray release];
[dataDictionary release];
dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
dataDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSDate * CurrentDate = start;
int i = 0;

NSMutableArray * arrayOfPerformancesForCurrentDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while(YES)
{
    i = 0;
    if ([arrayOfPerformancesForCurrentDate count] > 0)
    {
        [arrayOfPerformancesForCurrentDate removeAllObjects];   
    }

    for (i; i < self.arrayOfPerformances.count; i++)
    {
        Performance * performanceItem = [[Performance alloc] init]; 
        performanceItem = [self.arrayOfPerformances objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString * sPerformanceDate = [performanceItem.sDate substringToIndex:10];
        NSString * sCurrentDate = [CurrentDate dateDescription];

        if([sPerformanceDate isEqualToString:sCurrentDate])
        {
            [arrayOfPerformancesForCurrentDate addObject:performanceItem];
        }

        [performanceItem release];
    }

    if ([arrayOfPerformancesForCurrentDate count] >= 1)
    {
        [dataDictionary setObject:arrayOfPerformancesForCurrentDate forKey:CurrentDate];
        [dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    }
    else
    {
        [dataArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }

    TKDateInformation info = [CurrentDate dateInformation];
    info.day++;
    CurrentDate = [NSDate dateFromDateInformation:info];
    if([CurrentDate compare:end]==NSOrderedDescending) break;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I dont understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part doesn't look right:

```
Performance * performanceItem = [[Performance alloc] init];     <--
performanceItem = [self.arrayOfPerformances objectAtIndex:i];   <--

NSString * sPerformanceDate = [performanceItem.sDate substringToIndex:10];
NSString * sCurrentDate = [CurrentDate dateDescription];

if([sPerformanceDate isEqualToString:sCurrentDate])
{
    [arrayOfPerformancesForCurrentDate addObject:performanceItem];
}

[performanceItem release];                                      <--
```

You alloc+init performanceItem but then set it to an object in arrayOfPerformances and then you release it (while it's pointing to the object in arrayOfPerformances).

Change that section to this:

```
Performance *performanceItem = [self.arrayOfPerformances objectAtIndex:i];

NSString * sPerformanceDate = [performanceItem.sDate substringToIndex:10];
NSString * sCurrentDate = [CurrentDate dateDescription];

if([sPerformanceDate isEqualToString:sCurrentDate])
{
    [arrayOfPerformancesForCurrentDate addObject:performanceItem];
}

//don't release performanceItem
```

Comment: Cheers, that works. I do not know why i was alloc and init'ing the Performance class, for some reason i thought i had to alloc init a blank Performance in order to assign a already created object to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think arrayOfPerformances of being destroyed. It appears you aren't even initializing it anywhere.

Comment: This is not the complete code, it gets initialized in other code. By that part it has 48 objects in it and as it goes through the loops the array gets destroyed.